# VBA in Excel userform and pivot tables/userforms

Tags: vba, excel

I have 0 experience with visual basic but come from PHP/mysql.

I have a requirement of creating a userform where by multiple products can be selected and a list of raw ingredients that make these ingredients is output.

I have created a rawingredients sheet, products sheet and a pivot table.

I have got as far as populating a multiselect listbox with the product names, I need a way of assigning the values the id(row number) and using this to look up the pivot table for all ingredients and add these to a text area.

```
Private Sub Userform_Initialize()

ListBox1.List = sheets(2).Range("B1:B9").Value

End Sub
```

I have tried googling a way of assigning an id to the values but am struggling and wondering if my method of tackling this problem is incorrect as it is how I would achieve it as a website.

Any direction to this would be greatly received.

**Edit**

```
ingredient_id  name
1  fishmeal
2  fish oil
3  soya bean meal
4  guar meal
5  soya bean oil
6  salt
7  meat and bone meal
8  green dye

product_id  name
1  Expander Pellets
2  Feed Pellets
3  Green Pellets

product_id  ingredient_id
1  1
1  2
1  3
1  4
2  1
2  5
2  3
2  6
3  7
3  8
3  2
```

Using the above table data I need a list box containing the 3 product names, any number of these products can be selected. Once finished selecting a button will generate a textbox with the ingredients by looking up which ingredients belong to products on the pivot table.

I hope this clearer.

I may not need to use a pivot table but from my background this is how it would be achieved in PHP/mysql.

Comment: Please explain once more, maybe in points, what are you trying to achieve. You put like 4 separate things into 1 sentence, which is making every particular of them a bit enigmatic.

Comment: added an edit hopefully clears it up?

Comment: You are storing this tables in some excel sheet, am I right?

Comment: each table is on a separate sheet currently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to put relational base logic into Excel, where Excel does not support such an idea. The following solution is best what I can come up with.

```
Private Sub Userform_Initialize()
    ListBox1.List = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E2:E4").Value
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim prod_id As Integer
Dim output As String
Dim r As Integer
Dim ingrArr() As Variant

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If ListBox1.Selected(i) Then
            prod_id = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & i + 2).Value
            j = 2
            Do While Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G" & j).Value <> ""
                If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("G" & j).Value = prod_id Then
                    r = Sheets("Sheet1").Columns("A:A").Find(What:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("H" & j).Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchFormat:=False).Row

                    If Not IsInArray(.Range("A" & r).Value, ingrArr) Then
                        output = output & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & r).Value & vbNewLine
                        On Error GoTo ErrHand2:
                            ReDim Preserve ingrArr(1 To UBound(ingrArr) + 1)
                        On Error GoTo 0
ErrHand2:
                        If Err <> 0 Then
                            Err = 0
                            ReDim Preserve ingrArr(1 To 1)
                        End If
                        ingrArr(UBound(ingrArr)) = .Range("A" & r).Value
                    End If

                End If
                j = j + 1
            Loop
        End If
    Next i
End With

MsgBox output

End Sub

Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo ErrHand1:
        IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)
    On Error GoTo 0
ErrHand1:
    If Err <> 0 Then
        Err = 0
        IsInArray = False
    End If
End Function
```

I put my data in one sheet named `Sheet1`, in form you can see at the picture. You can easily fit it to your workbook by changing sheets names and ranges.

[image: pic1]

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you so much. I suspected I may of been trying to go about it the wrong way. I don't understand each bit of the code but I can doctor it, I have made it output to a textbox and each value in output is comma seperated.

Comment: Is there an easy way to remove duplicate raw ingredients from the output?

Comment: The cleanest solution I see is to create array with used `ingredient_id` and check every time if current `ingredient_id` is on this list.

Comment: Limak Im struggling with the syntax to even create arrays in visual basic.... they seem to want to declare the length of the array or have to use redim everytime which apparently is a bad idea in a loop?

Comment: See my edit. I know it is very confusing, but had to do this to get rid of problem with execute functions on empty arrays. Abstract data types in VBA are very poorly implemented.

Comment: wow, no wonder i was struggling with arrays, i get a runtime error with this though. Compile Error: Invalid ReDim The line under 'On Error GoTo ErrHand2":